# Create a boolean mask from the intersection of 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

Given 2 arrays (really, matrixes) of identical shape, what's the *best* way to extract a boolean mask from their intersection? That is, True if the items at each matrix position are equal, False if the item comparison fails.

I am trying to avoid syntactically iterating over the arrays, and it seems there must be a operator or elegant way to boolean compare them resulting in a mask.

Once the mask is generated, the idea is to use it to return an index of matching positions.

The items are non-numeric (strings).

Comment: When you say "array", do you really mean nested lists? Or are you using something like NumPy?

Answer (score 0):

If your two arrays (lets call them A and B) are numpy arrays you could just do:

```
Mask = A==B
print("Mask = ",Mask)
```

Comment: This looks promising; looking forward to trying it.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy where

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

```
image = np.where(matrix2, WhiteImage, matrix1).astype(np.uint8)
```

You need to create 3rd matrix with same shape, make it like

```
WhiteImage = np.zeros((height,width,X), np.uint8)
```

If your arrays arent numpys just convert it using

```
matrix1 = np.array(matrix)
```

Comment: Seems more verbose than other suggested answer, but will try this one too.